# How use VueJS with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, requirejs

I want to configure VueJS with RequireJS. I am using this vueJS library: https://cdn.rawgit.com/edgardleal/require-vuejs/aeaff6db/dist/require-vuejs.min.js.

This is my require congif file:

```
require.config({
baseUrl : "js",
paths : {
    jquery : "libs/jquery-3.2.1.min",
    fullcalendar : "libs/fullcalendar.min",
    bootstrap : "libs/bootstrap.min",
    vue : "libs/vue",
    parsley : "libs/validation/parsley.min",
    esParsley : "libs/validation/es",
    noty : "libs/noty/jquery.noty.packaged.min",
    session : "service/sessionService",
    handlebars : "libs/handlebars-v4.0.8",
    menu : "view/menu/menu",
    'datatables.net' : "libs/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min",
    jquerydatatables : "libs/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min",
},
shim : {
    "jquery" : {
        deps : []
    },
    "menu" : {
        deps : [ 'jquery' ]
    },
    "bootstrap" : {
        deps : [ 'jquery' ]
    },
    "parsley" : {
        deps : [ 'jquery' ]
    },
    "esParsley" : {
        deps : [ 'parsley' ]
    },
    "noty" : {
        deps : [ 'jquery' ]
    },
    "jquerydatatables" : {
        deps : [ 'jquery', 'bootstrap' ]
    },
    "datatables.net" : {
        deps : [ 'jquerydatatables', 'jquery' ]
    },
    "vue": {
        "exports": "vue"
        }
    }
});
require([ 'jquery', document.getElementById("idModule").value, 'parsley',
        'menu', 'bootstrap', 'esParsley', 'datatables.net'], function($, Module, parsley, menu) {
    menu.init();
    Module.init();
});
```

Went I try this code, I obtain one error. The error is this:[image]

Can you help me? Thank you very much. David.

Answer (score 0):

require-vuejs is not the vuejs library. require-vuejs is used for dynamic loading of file components.

This is the [vuejs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js) library you need.

Comment: Thank you @Scriptonomy, but when I copi this file in my project a obtain one error. The error is: `Syntax error on token "}", ( expected`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the included webpack from vue-cli3? it basically does the same and more and you don't have to configure/implement it yourself.

Here is a [guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html) from the docs to show you how to create a new project with the official vue-cli